# Apache Regexp 500 Internal Error

Tags: php, regex, apache, codeigniter

I want to rewrite all incoming URLs like: `host/lang-EN/product` to `host/index.php?lang=lang-EN/product` I want to do this for all URLs not changing anything what's after the `host/lang-EN/` just forward it to `host/index.php?lang=lang-EN/whatever was after lang-EN/`

This is what I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule     ^(.*)$               index.php/$1   [NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^index.php/(.*)/?$   index.php?lang=$1  [NC,L]
```

Resulting in Internal Error threw by Apache(last version). I am using Codeigniter as framework.

error.log:

```
[Sat Apr 05 12:59:32.044771 2014] [core:error] [pid 3600:tid 1680] [client ::1:3253] `AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`
```

Comment: Is there an entry in the error.log file?

Comment: Yes, I've included it now as well.

Comment: Of course this creates an endless redirect, because on the “next round” (rewriting configured in .htaccess is looped through multiple times, until none of the rules match any more) `^(.*)$` of course matches your `index.php?lang=foo` again.

Comment: @CBroe The goal is to get an url like `host/lang-EN/product` and call > `host/index.php?lang=lang-EN/product` with it.

Comment: @CBroe The first rule should match `/lang-EN` and redirect to `index.php/lang-EN` then the second rewrite should execute again which would match `index.php/lang-EN` and execute `index.php?lang=lang-EN` <- this should not have a match anymore. That's the goal.

Comment: As I already said, after that has happened, _the whole process starts again_ – and `^(.*)$` matches the `index.php` part in `index.php?lang=lang-EN`, so it gets rewritten to `index.php/index.php`, and then `^index.php/(.*)/?$` matches that again, so it gets rewritten to `index.php?lang=index.php` … and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with only this one to redirect `/host/...` to `/host/index.php...`

```
RewriteRule     ^/?(?!index\.php)(.*)$         index.php?lang=$1   [NC,L]
```

`(?!index.php)` is negative lookahead to check that there is no `index.php` at the beginning. So that it doesn't touch the urls like `/index.php?lang=...` to avoid recursively.

Comment: Throws Internal Error `[Sat Apr 05 12:59:32.044771 2014] [core:error] [pid 3600:tid 1680] [client ::1:3253] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` Possibly something that Codeigniter does afterwards triggers the error.

Comment: @Berky Did you remove your other two conditions and used only mine one?

Comment: @SabujHassan: I think by `host` the actual host name (domain name) is meant here, so it should not be part of the RewriteRule pattern.

Comment: @SabujHassan I removed my rules and replaced it with yours so I have only one condition.

Comment: @CBroe I have excluded that aswell.

Comment: @Berky Not sure how you discard the `/host` but I have edited my answer by removing that.

Comment: @SabujHassan I have improperly discarded the host. Your updated example works great!